# What does “Enable Editor Config” in the TortoiseMerge settings mean?

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

Tortoise Merge 1.9.3, the difference viewer that comes with the Tortoise Subversion client, has in its settings dialogue a tick-box setting for “Enable Editor Config”, just right of the “Tab Size” setting. The help for this dialogue does not describe this option, nor could I find it on-line, and I did not observe any effect of setting it — what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) is a format to specify how an editor should treat tab/spaces and other settings. Since TortoiseMerge can also edit files, it can use the config files in editorconfig format and act accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks, that sounds useful; is it already documented how much TortoiseMerge supports? I have only found the `/*reflectedname` options in the manual (2015/09/27 18:54:04 (r26833)), which give the impression that you have to specify four separate names. A link to more Tortoise documentation of Editor Config support, if available, would be appreciated. _(replacing 2 previous comments)_